# how to use react-native-tab-view's <tabbar>

Tags: android, react-native

I want to use TabBar from 
[React-native-tab-view package's  Section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view#tabbar-)

[image]

in android project, how to i use it? please provide a simple example with some props in it. thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you already tried the example from the docs in the url you provided? is there an issue that you are having?

Comment: there is a full example on TabView, which i did, and runs smoothly but when i try the example from the url i get an error and i could not resolve it. So I thought maybe my syntax is error so i just want some one to write code and i will check it with my own code.

Comment: please add the code that you tried to your question and show us what the error is. This way you can get help easier.